# Boot camp doesn’t recognize USB for LG Ultrafine 4k

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp

I have an LG Ultrafine 4k display and whenever I try to run Bootcamp it eventually says device not recognized and it won’t work. It’s a new monitor, so not sure what the issue is. I have 2017 Macbokk Pro

Answer (score 1):

Make sure these things work

1. displaying
2. charging for laptop
3. USB expansion ports
4. brightness adjustment (in BootCamp control panel)
5. speaker

Then nothing more could be expected from this display. The error might due to no driver for the ambient light sensor (macOS doesn't utilize it either).